# Is there supposed to be a dev folder in OS X?

Tags: macbook, osx-mountain-lion

I have the latest version of Mountain Lion installed. I'm curious - is the dev folder only supposed to be on a system in the developer version of the OS, or is it in all versions?

Comment: Why do you care? What's your actual problem?

Comment: Do you mean the developer-folder which is created by xcode? Nowadays everything is in the xcode.app-package.

Comment: You mean `/dev` as device files in Linux, or `/Developer` from old Xcode versions?

Comment: Woah, no need for hostility. I am curious. That's my "actual problem." The /dev folder is hidden unless I list what's on the drive in Terminal. I do not have Xcode installed.

Comment: Nobody is being hostile towards you. Your question lacks a bit of context and details, which makes people ask for a little more information in order to be able to answer it.

Comment: Well. I'm running Mountain Lion on a Macbook Pro. In Terminal, when I type "cd /", there's a folder called /dev, which is hidden in Finder (I have that set to show all files). Inside of it, there are several dozen folders with a mix of letters and numbers in the names, which seem to be empty. This is just a home computer, I do not use Xcode or do any development work. If it isn't clear, I'm a computer noob, as you might say. I'm just curious if the folder is meant for a developer install of the OS, or if it in every install of Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev` has nothing to do with developing. It's a common mount point for [a device file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) in Linux and several Unix-like operating systems.

Since OS X is a BSD-flavored Unix and certified as such, it also implements the device file system. This is present on every OS X version.